# React Native: passing data between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a small app, but have many questions)
I have 3 screen and use react-navigation to pass data. the scheme is following:

```
1) loading screen (fetch data and save it to AsyncStorage+handling data and save to obj1 for pickers)
(pass obj1)
2)main screen (get data,render pickers based on it, take selected values and pass them next)
(pass pickers selection+input)
3)some results(get data from Asyncstorage, some calculating and render results)
```

so I have two questions.

when I navigate back from 3) to 2) I have an error that screen2 need data, which was passed from screen1. yes - i've checked if this data pass to 3 and then to 2 when Back Button is pressed, and there is no error, but I'm sure this is bad solution

and  second..trying to explain) on screen 3 some calculations made on pickers selection, so it hasn't problem. but rest of them needed get data from AsyncStorage and then convert it according to Picker values and render to ListView. Despite I'm putting getting from AS on componentWillMount it's still take much time so data for rendering is undefined. Of course I'm using states, but I think this is a bad logic of data handling..

UPD
so I'm trying pass data from child(screen) to parent(index.ios.js), where it define as first loading view( I'm using navigator's stack screens)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      };
  }
  myCallback(dataFromChild) {
      console.log("yeah", dataFromChild);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LoadingScreen callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}/>
    );
  }
}
```

and LoadingScreen.js:

```
render() {
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#dc143c', marginTop:20}}>
          <Image
              source={require('./WhiteLogo.png')}
              style={{flex:3, height: undefined, width: undefined, marginLeft:20, marginRight:20}}
              resizeMode="contain"
              qwer={this.props.callbackFromParent('listInfo').bind(this)}
            />
          <Spinner color='white' style={{flex:1}}/>
        </View>
   );
  }
}
```

and I've got an error "Unhandled JS Exception: this.props.callbackFromParent is not a function"

Comment: what is the error navigating back from screen3 to screen2? react-native just keep its previous state passed down from screen1, isn't that enough? Or you mean in screen3 you changed something, and then need to update screen2 accordingly?

Comment: for screen3 logic, if you really got too many data based on screen2 picker and require long time calculation, how long will that be? would a `ActivityIndicator` sufficient?

Comment: @Val so when screen2 loading it needs some object from screen1 with data. and when i use back button from screen3 to screen2 got an error like "object is undefined". when i pass this obj from screen2 to screen3(where it actually doesn't need) and then to screen3 back with the same name, the error is gone. this is bad solution, now i'm trying pass it to parent of the screens but have some problems too(have updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncStorage might not be the best solution for what you are trying. Using `react-navigation` for data delivery is not the best neither. I would suggest checking redux for storing states globally and delivering it to the pages when needed. There is also another way which is passing functions to the props of child components for pulling up any data from child to parent components. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875787/pass-state-from-child-to-parent-component-in-react-native) and [this](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17) or the sample code is below.

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends Component {
    updateState (data) {
        this.setState(data);
    }
    render() {
        <View>
            <Child updateParentState={this.updateState.bind(this)} />
        </View>
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
class Child extends Component {    
    render() {
      <View>
        <Button title="Change" onPress={() => {this.props.updateParentState({name: 'test})}} />
      </View>
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'm trying apply passing from child to parent and I've got an error _Unhandled JS Exception: this.props.callbackFromParent is not a function_ , can you please check my code above?